# What should be the recurrence solution of f(n)=(1-f(n-1))*c+f(n-1), where f(0)=c?

Tags: python, algorithm, recurrence

I have an equation that I need to code.
But the equation is in the form,  `f(n)=(1-f(n-1))*c+f(n-1)`,
where `f(0)=c`.
Now, it is quite similar to the **Fibonacci series**, so obviously it will take exponential time and slow down my entire process.

Then, how I can theoretically devise the recurrence solution and find an alternative way of efficient code structure?

Comment: *"obviously it will take exponential time"* - Only if you do it in a very naive way.

Comment: "it is quite similar to the Fibonacci series, so obviously it will take exponential time and slow down my entire process." - well, no, it can be calculated in linear time, and you can even easily find a formula to get the solution directly, so in O(1).

Comment: Are you sure about the recurrence formula? Fibonacci has `f(n-2)` in its recurrence relation, but this one depends only on `f(n-1)`, which is a *lot* simpler. Is there a typo in the formula you gave?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Can you show that O(1) solution? I doubt that exists, as larger n can result in larger f(n) and I don't think it can be computed in constant time.

Comment: @trincot It is not a typo. I wrote the exact formula that I am using.

Comment: So then it is not related to Fibonacci's series at all.

Comment: So, is it possible to keep the time complexity under O(1)?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille If I'm not mistaken, it's `f(n) = 1 - (1-c)**(n+1)`, whose (absolute) values can grow exponentially, so can't be computed in O(1). No?

Comment: The recurrence can be resolved to a closed formula, giving a O(1) solution. See my answer.

Comment: @trincot As you got the same formula as my above comment, can you answer my question of how that's supposed to be O(1)?

Comment: It is O(1) if we assume CPU integer words as boundary, where these mathematical operations happen in constant time. There are two ways to speak of complexity. If we go to the more theoretical level, then the complexity needs to take into account the operations for arbitrary sizes. This is certainly more pure, but not always how complexity is discussed.

Comment: @KellyBundy there's ambiguity in the question between f(n), and the time it takes to compute f(n). f(n) is an exponential, but can be computed efficiently with a single pow. Further ambiguity is that if 0<=c<2, then f(n) is O(1), since the base of the exponential has magnitude <= 1.

Comment: (Just to add to the confusion, I think it's fairer to consider integer exponentation a^b as taking Theta(Log b) arithmetic operations since I don't think exponentiation is a basic arithmetic operation, although it depends on your definitions.

Comment: @trincot With that boundary excuse, *every* such function is O(1), no? Not particularly meaningful, and rather misleading.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, something like Theta(Log b), I think.

Comment: @KellyBundy your argumentative style isn't helping the discussion, but the transdichotomous model is a well-used model of computational complexity. (re: trincot's point about integer words etc.).

Comment: @PaulHankin So the transdichotomous model considers exponentiation to be O(1) just like addition and multiplication? Where can I read about that?

Comment: Kelly, yes that is true, but note how it is common to make that "simplification" when discussing less fundamental programming tasks. For instance, see the table of time complexity on [comparative sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts).

Comment: @trincot That's the table for algorithms that make *no* assumptions about the values other than comparability (in O(1)). The table for algorithms that *do* consider for example fixed width integers is in the very next section [Non-comparison sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Non-comparison_sorts) on that same page, and in those complexities, you find plenty of k, r and d in addition to just n.

Comment: Yes, and my point is that such assumptions are often made (here: comparability), ... depending on context. But hey, I added a paragraph to my answer. No need to continue the debate ,-)

Answer (score 3):

The formula is not like Fibonacci, as it only depends on the previous result, while the Fibonacci series depend on the 2 previous terms.

First you should convert the equation in such a way that the previous term only appears once, not twice. This was given:

= (1 − <sub>−1</sub>) + <sub>−1</sub>

But this can be rewritten as:

= (1 − )<sub>−1</sub> +

Now let's analyse how this formula expands, starting from the base case:

<sub>0</sub> =

<sub>1</sub> = (1−)<sub>0</sub> + 
         = (1−) +

<sub>2</sub> = (1−)<sub>1</sub> + 
         = (1−)[(1−) + ] + 
         = (1−)<sup>2</sup> + (1−) +

<sub>3</sub> = (1−)<sub>2</sub> + 
         = (1−)[(1−)<sup>2</sup> + (1−) + ] + 
         = (1−)<sup>3</sup> + (1−)<sup>2</sup> + (1−) +

...

= ∑<sub><sub>=0..</sub></sub>(1−)<sup>k</sup>
         = ∑<sub><sub>=0..</sub></sub>(1−)<sup>k</sup>

The sum is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula), and so we can write:

= (1 − (1−)<sup>+1</sup>) / (1 − (1−))
         = 1 − (1−)<sup>+1</sup>

Obviously that is easy to program as a O(1) algorithm.

This complexity assumes that arithmetic operations take constant time in the chosen programming language. If however, arbitrary large (big) integers are going to be used, then these arithmetic operations do not take constant time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If I suppose that the n is large then what should be the final time complexity?

Comment: What is the reasoning using arbitrarily large integers? Is it that n must be very limited, as otherwise the result value doesn't fit in for example a 32-bit int? Or is it something else? And what about modular exponentiation (for example modulo a 31-bit prime), which doesn't have that issue, would that be considered O(1) as well?

Comment: @Michaylor, that depends on the algorithm used for exponentiation, which in itself depends on the algorithm for multiplication. These are very specialised topics, with several competing algorithms that compete on time complexities. See for instance on multiplication [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs). Because of the dependency on how programming languages perform arithmetic operations on big integers (if they provide this natively), and they may use different algos, this goes beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Btw I started the same, rewriting to f(n) = (1-c)*f(n-1) + c. Then realized that it's just a number in base 1-c where all digits are c, leading to that sum without a desire to expand for a few small n.

Answer (score 2):

```
 f(n) = (1-f(n-1))*c + f(n-1)
      = c - c*f(n-1) + f(n-1)
      = c + (1-c)*f(n-1)
```

This is not exponential, and it's not similar to Fibonacci series. It is in the form:   `f(n) = a*f(n-1) + b`

You can implement this directly, which will be linear time (making `O(n)` calls to the function `f`).

**Or**, you can reduce the equation to a direct expression by solving the linear, first-order recurrence relation, which will get you:

```
f(n) = 1 - (1-c)^n + c*(1-c)^n
```

Which can be calculated in `O(1)`

Comment: Thus time complexity is linear?

Comment: @MichaylorRiya: It depends how you implemented it. It can be linear or constant. I updated my answer.

Comment: Is `^` xor or exponentiation? (This is a Python question and you formatted it as code). If the latter, how is that supposed to be O(1)?

Comment: I.e., see reasoning in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603004/what-should-be-the-recurrence-solution-of-fn-1-fn-1cfn-1-where-f0-c#comment121240552_68603004).

Comment: The last equation simplifies, since -(1-c)^n + c(1-c)^n = -(1-c)(1-c)^n = -(1-c)^(n+1). This agrees with the answer of @trincot.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you the recursive code.

```
c = 2 # You can use any number.

def algorithm(num):
    if not num: return c #(returns c if num == 0
    fminus1 = algorithm(num - 1)
    return (1 - fminus1) * c + fminus1
```

Answer (score 0):

This recurrence solves to

> **f(n) = -(1 - c)<sup>n+1</sup> + 1.**

To see why, let’s first notice that the recursive step can be rewritten as

> f(n) = (1 - c)f(n - 1) + c.

This is a linear heterogenous recurrence relation. To solve it, we first solve the related equation

> f(n) = (1 - c)f(n - 1)

to get the general solution f(n) = a(1 - c)<sup>n</sup>.

Next, we look for any solution to the general recurrence

> f(n) = (1 - c)f(n - 1) + c

and add that in. We’ll guess the answer is of the form s, since that’s generally how these things work, and then solve the equation

> f(n) = (1 - c)f(n - 1)+ c → s = (1 - c)(s) + c

This means that

> s = (1 - c)s + c
>
> s - (1 - c)s = c
> s(1 - 1 + c) = c
>
> cs = c
>
> s = 1

So the general form of the solution will be a(1 - c)<sup>n</sup> + 1. Solving for the boundary condition f(0) = c gives

> a(1 - c)<sup>0</sup> + 1 = c
>
> a + 1 = c
>
> a = c - 1

So the recurrence solves to

> f(n) = (c - 1)(1 - c)<sup>n</sup> + 1,

or

> **f(n) = -(1 - c)<sup>n+1</sup> + 1.**

Let’s try this out. For c = 0, we get f(n) = -1<sup>n</sup> + 1 = 0, and we have

- f(0) = 0
- f(1) = (1 - 0)f(0) + 0 = 0
- f(2) = (1 - 0)f(1) + 0 = 0
- …

For c = 1, we have f(n) = -(1 - 1)<sup>n</sup> + 1 = 1, and we have

- f(0) = 1
- f(1) = (1 - 1)f(0) + 1 = 1
- f(2) = (1 - 1)f(1) + 1 = 1
- …